# Bokeh multi_line not showing

Tags: python, bokeh

I want to plot circles and multi_lines together with bokeh but for some reason it does not plot the multi_line. My multi_line `df1` looks like:

```
                       x                                y
0   [4.9223553, 4.9223667, 4.9223853]   [52.3654363, 52.3654277, 52.3654169]
1   [4.9279354, 4.9280225, 4.9280546, 4.928041, 4....   [52.3619809, 52.362025, 52.3621167, 52.3622213...
2   [4.9261096, 4.9260732, 4.9258198]   [52.3663263, 52.3662732, 52.3661229]
3   [4.9308652, 4.9308238, 4.9307548, 4.9304676, 4...   [52.3659402, 52.3657291, 52.3655389, 52.364919...
4   [4.881478, 4.8816828, 4.881693] [52.361566, 52.361699, 52.3617067]
```

while my circle plot `df2` looks like this:

```
       lng         lat
0   4.867565    52.365994
1   4.908305    52.346692
2   4.853705    52.370595
3   4.880385    52.373292
4   4.939076    52.35316
```

my plotting code:

```
source1 = ColumnDataSource(df1)
source2 = ColumnDataSource(df2)

p = figure(title= "VRI + Roads", plot_width=900, plot_height=900)

hover = HoverTool(names=['vri_points'])
hover.tooltips=[('VRI', '@kruispuntn'),
                ('Kruispunt', '@kruispunt')]

p.multi_line('x', 'y', source = source1, color='green', line_width=0.5)
p.circle('lng', 'lat', source = source2, name='vri_points', color='red', size=5, hover_line_color="black")

p.add_tools(hover)

show(p)
```

I have no clue why it does not plot the multi_line plot. could someone help me? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You did not include the full data in your question, so I can't say for sure. But I tried with the data that you did provide, and the `multi_line` did work just fine. One potential issue - the segments are pretty short so it's easy to miss them.